# activemq apollo create broker error

Tags: apache-2.2, activemq

I have been trying to create a broker on my activemq apache-apollo 1.6 installation. When I execute the following command:

```
$APOLLO_HOME/bin/apollo create log1broker
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /usr/local/lib64/activemq/apache-apollo-1/6
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .usr.local.lib64.activemq.apache-apollo-1.6
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: /usr/local/lib64/activemq/apache-apollo-1.6. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the `apollo` startup script assumes your `PWD` is `$APOLLO_HOME`.

Do it in this order instead:

```
$ cd $APOLLO_HOME
$ ./bin/apollo create log1broker
```